# Enable SPD 2013 under Group O365 Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365-groups

I tried to open my new Group O365 Site with SPD 2013 but I get this error msg:

> "403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN403 FORBIDDEN"

I understand that I should enable SharePoint designer for this site but I couldn't find "SharePoint Designer Settings" under Site settings->Site Collection Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to **Allow or prevent custom script** under SharePoint Admin settings. It will take 24 hours to take effect.  Have a look at [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Allow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: In fact Custom Scripts are allowed in SharePoint Admin Center and i can work with SPD in our principal SC (https://Mytenant.sharepoint.com) but when i created a group O365 site and i wanted to work with SPD it's not allowed

Comment: I was able to work with O365 group and SPD so it might be something specific to your tenant configuration.  You can try this PS Set-SPOsite <SiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0